# Proof of $f(A \cup B) \subset f(A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I had a test yesterday and that was one of the questions:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets, and let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $X$. It's true that $f(A \cup B) \subset f(A)$?

I thought it was false, but my teacher said it was true. If someone can help me, I would like to understand why it's true.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $A\cap B$? I mean $f(\{1\}\cup\{2\})$ certainly is not a subset of $f({1})$

Comment: Perhaps you were given that $f(B) \subset f(A)$ as an additional condition.

Comment: @DavidP Unless $f(1) = f(2)$ :p

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yes, of course :)

Comment: "Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets, and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $X$. It's true that $f(A \cup B) \subset f(A)$?"
**If I got that question on a test I would confidently say it's false and continue**.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $f(x)=x$ and $A=[0,1], B=[1,2]$. Obviously, $[0,1] \not\subset [0,2] $, so, possibly, your teacher means some additional assumptions or some other rule.

For example, holds: 1. $f(A \cup B)\subset f(A)\cup f(B)$,
2. $f(A \cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: In your example you have equality, not just inclusion. Can you think of a better thing the teacher might have meant?

Comment: @Ethan Bolker. Of course there is equality, but I tried to write such expression,  which is something similar to OP. Anyway, added second, where only injection grants reverse inclusion. May be you have some more examples?